# Getting unknown property Exception in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

here I have a model in yii2

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "car_ad".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $brand_id
 * @property integer $sub_brand_id
 * @property integer $sell_type
 * @property integer $year
 * @property integer $the_function
 * @property integer $fuel_type_id
 * @property integer $gearbox
 * @property integer $sell_mode
 * @property integer $real_price
 * @property integer $prepayment
 * @property integer $installment_price
 * @property integer $no_installments
 * @property integer $delivery_time_id
 * @property integer $installments_period
 * @property integer $body_status_id
 * @property integer $body_color_id
 * @property integer $inside_color_id
 * @property integer $number_type
 * @property string $description
 * @property integer $ad_type_id
 * @property integer $provice_id
 * @property integer $city_id
 * @property string $address
 * @property string $lang
 * @property string $lat
 * @property string $creation_date
 * @property integer $user_id
 */
class CarAd extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $imageFiles;
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'car_ad';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['brand_id', 'sub_brand_id', 'sell_type', 'year', 'used_value', 'fuel_type_id', 'gearbox', 'body_status_id', 'body_color_id', 'number_type', 'ad_type_id', 'provice_id', 'city_id', 'address', 'lang', 'lat', 'creation_date', 'user_id'], 'required'],
            [['brand_id', 'sub_brand_id', 'sell_type', 'year', 'fuel_type_id', 'used_value ', 'gearbox', 'sell_mode', 'real_price', 'prepayment', 'installment_price', 'no_installments', 'delivery_time_id', 'installments_period', 'body_status_id', 'body_color_id', 'inside_color_id', 'number_type', 'ad_type_id', 'provice_id', 'city_id', 'creation_date', 'user_id'], 'integer'],            
            [['description'], 'string'],
            [['address', 'lang', 'lat'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
            [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'maxFiles' => 10],
        ];
    }

    public function upload()
    {   

        foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
            $image = New CarAdImage();            
            $image->image = $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension;
            $image->car_ad_id = $this->id;
            $image->save();
            $file->saveAs('img/car_ad/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
        }        
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'شناسه', 'brand_id' => 'برند', 'sub_brand_id' => 'مدل','sell_type' => 'فروش به صورت',
            'year' => 'سال','used_value' => 'کارکرد','fuel_type_id' => 'سیستم سوخت','gearbox' => 'گیربکس',
            'sell_mode' => 'نوع فروش','real_price' => 'قیمت نقدی','prepayment' => 'پیش پرداخت','installment_price' => 'مبلغ هر قسط','no_installments' => 'تعداد اقساط','delivery_time_id' => 'موعد تحویل',
            'installments_period' => 'دوره پرداخت',
            'body_status_id' => 'وضعیت بدنه',
            'body_color_id' => 'رنگ بدنه',
            'inside_color_id' => 'رنگ داخل',
            'number_type' => 'نوع پلاک',
            'description' => 'توضیحات اضافی',
            'ad_type_id' => 'نوع آگهی',
            'provice_id' => 'استان',
            'city_id' => 'شهرستان',
            'address' => 'آدرس',
            'lang' => 'طول جغرافیایی',
            'lat' => 'عرض جغرافیایی',
            'creation_date' => 'تاریخ ایجاد',
            'user_id' => 'کاربر ایجاد کننده',
            'imageFiles' => 'تصاویر آگهی'
        ];
    }
}
```

when I want to submit the form I face with this error.

`Getting unknown property: app\models\CarAd::used_value`

but as you see I have this field in my fields. 
My table name is `car_ad`.
what is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because this field is not present in the @property comment I guess you have added it after the model has been generated. If you have got the DB schema cached new fields are not fetched until cache is updated. Try to remove the cache for DB.

Comment: I hav changed the field in the database, first it's name was the_function and I have got same error then I renamed it and nothing changed

Comment: So there is no `'enableSchemaCache' => true` in your DB connection config?

Comment: no there isn;t. I have refresh the schema in my action too :(

Comment: I've noticed there is space at the end of this name in the second row of rules. Maybe this is the cause?

Comment: You can execute `Yii::$app->cache->flush();` in any controller to clear cache, It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Yii::$app->cache->flush(); worked for me too

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30799394)

Comment: I got it, but I can't to vote, because I have not enaugh reputation